# How to reflect multiple input field value to single field using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i have four fields out of that 3 are accept characters and one accept number (out of 4 field first character field and last number field is mandatory and rest are optional) what ever the data they enter in four fields, it should show in result field.

Hear in number field what ever the number they enter that should convert into some common character i.e if they enter '3' that should show as 'NNN'

```
i will give one eg: 

1Field = BB 
2Field = CC
3Field = AA
4Field = 3
```

result = ' BBCCAANNN '

HTML:

```
<input name="a" id="textBoxt1" ></input>
<input name="b" id="textBoxt1" ></input>
<input name="c" id="textBoxt1" ></input>
<input name="d" id="textBoxt1" ></input>
<input name="result" id="result"></input>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^="textBox"]').keyup(function(){
        var result = '';
        $('[id^="textBox"]').each(function(){
            var count = parseInt($(this).val(),10) || 0;
            result += Array(count+1).join($(this).val()); 
        });
        $('#result').val(result);
    });
});
```

i think i can convert fourth field value to character by using this :

```
     result += Array(count+1).join($(this).data('char')); // in JQUERY

and in HTML 

<input name="d" id="textBoxt1" data-char="N" ></input>
```

but it's not working fine, how can i do this. Any help will be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: when you enter as 3 why you want it as N?

Comment: Where does N come from, and should this apply to only the last field or all of them, as you're iterating over all the fields in your code. As a sidenote, inputs are self closing and ID's are unique ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FYUSF/

Comment: you can have a variable initialized with ' N ' and all id's are unique , inputs will enter by users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try his http://jsfiddle.net/pE5wS/

```
var comm="N";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[id^="textBox"]').keyup(function(){
        var result = '';
        $('[id^="textBox"]:lt(3)').each(function(){
            result += $(this).val(); 
        });
         $('[id^="textBox"]:eq(3)').each(function(){
            var cnt=$(this).val();
             while(cnt!=0)
             {result += comm; 
              cnt--;
             }
        });
        $('#result').val(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i found one problem if i enter character in number field (i don't want to allow character but just for checking wither it allow or not) hole browser will stuck ...?

Comment: any how thanks, itś working fine after some modification. I updated feddle pleas see this http://jsfiddle.net/pE5wS/1/